# Allow duplicate downloads with Scrapy Image Pipeline?

Tags: python, scrapy, pipeline

Please see below an example version of my code, which uses the Scrapy Image Pipeline to download/scrape images from a site:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from imageExtract.items import ImageextractItem

class ExtractSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'extract'
    start_urls = ['url']

    def parse(self, response):
        image = ImageextractItem()
        titles = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
        rel = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6']

        image['title'] = titles
        image['image_urls'] = rel
        return image
```

It all works fine but as per default settings, avoids downloading duplicates. Is there any way of overriding this so that I can download the duplicates also? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one possible solution is to create your own image pipeline inherited from `scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline` with overridden method `get_media_requests` (see [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#module-scrapy.pipelines.files) for example). While yielding the `scrapy.Request`, pass `dont_filter=True` to the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it didn't seem to work. I suspect there may be some 'duplicate detection code' within the image pipeline source itself - but from reviewing the code, I can't seem to find it anywhere. If I could locate that, I could maybe update it so that I can pass in pass in a custom arg to skip this.

Comment: I think I've found it, take a look at method `_process_request` of class `MediaPipeline` ([link](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/media.py)). It takes file from cache if it was already downloaded (based on request fingerprint). Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way how to customize it with any argument or setting.

Comment: Thank you! I will try comment out/adjust some of the source and see if I can find a way to make it work for my application.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Tomáš's instruction, eventually I found a way to download duplicate images.

In `_process_request` of class `MediaPipeline`, I comment these lines.

`# Return cached result if request was already seen
        # if fp in info.downloaded:
        #     return defer_result(info.downloaded[fp]).addCallbacks(cb, eb)`

`# Check if request is downloading right now to avoid doing it twice
        # if fp in info.downloading:
        #     return wad`

An uncatched KeyError would occur but it seems not affect my result so I stopped digging further.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome KeyError mentioned by Rick, what I did was:

Look for the function `_cache_result_and_execute_waiters` also in the class `MediaPipeline`, you will see a similar if case as shown below

```
if isinstance(result, Failure):
   # minimize cached information for failure 
   result.cleanFailure()
   result.frames = []
   result.stack = None
```

I added another if case to check if `fp` is in `info.waiting`, and everything after that go inside this case

```
if fp in info.waiting:
    info.downloading.remove(fp)  
    info.downloaded[fp] = result  # cache result
    for wad in info.waiting.pop(fp):
        defer_result(result).chainDeferred(wad)
```

In the debug log, the path name in `"images"` of your scrapy Item is still incorrect though. But I got it saved in the correct path by creating a list of image names for all my `"image_urls"`

Answer (score 0):

> https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c5627af15bcf413c04539aeb47dd07cf8b3e4092/scrapy/pipelines/media.py#L99

```
        # Return cached result if request was already seen
        if fp in info.downloaded:
            return defer_result(info.downloaded[fp]).addCallbacks(cb, eb)

        # Otherwise, wait for result
        wad = Deferred().addCallbacks(cb, eb)
        info.waiting[fp].append(wad)
```

Since the fp was fingerprint of a request, which implements below:

> https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c5627af15bcf413c04539aeb47dd07cf8b3e4092/scrapy/utils/request.py#L35

```
def request_fingerprint(
    request: Request,
    include_headers: Optional[Iterable[Union[bytes, str]]] = None,
    keep_fragments: bool = False,
) -> str:
    """
    Return the request fingerprint as an hexadecimal string.

    The request fingerprint is a hash that uniquely identifies the resource the
    request points to. For example, take the following two urls:


    http://www.example.com/query?id=111&cat=222
    http://www.example.com/query?cat=222&id=111

    Even though those are two different URLs both point to the same resource
    and are equivalent (i.e. they should return the same response).
...
```

I think it would be more gracefully by adding some random params to the image url, instead of commenting some source code.

Like this:

```
...
class YourImagePipelineClass(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        url = item.get('img_url') + '?<some_params_key>=%s' % str(time.time())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, meta=item, dont_filter=True)
...
```